# Stream a live video call between 2 people to thousands of people

Tags: streaming, webrtc

How can i stream a live video call between 2 people, to thousands of people. I prefer to use webRTC but I can't find the answer to my question. The viewers should be able to watch the stream in a web app.

Answer (score 1):

Streaming to thousands of people is not trivial! It's not as hard as it used to be 10 years ago but is still pretty hard.

WebRTC supports direct browser to browser (peer to peer) connections. This means that WebRTC is primarily targeted at 1:1 conversation. If you want the same conversation (video or audio) to be shared among more than 2 people you have the following options:

- Connect any user to any other user. This creates a fully connected graph between the viewers. This is easy to do because all you need is webrtc. No special hardware/software. However it is also very inefficient in thems of trafic and distribution and doesn't scale boyound 5-6 people.
- Use A WebRTC Video relay like [Jitsi VideoBridge](https://jitsi.org/Projects/JitsiVideobridge). According to the [official performance claims](https://jitsi.org/Projects/JitsiVideobridgePerformance) VideoBridge can scale to 500-1000 people given fast and wide enough internet connection.
- Direct the Webrtc stream between the two participants to a WebRTC enabled streaming server. If needed, transcode the input stream to a suitalbe codex - x264/VP8/VP9. Convert the input stream to a sutable protocl - [RTMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol)/[HLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Adaptive_Streaming_over_HTTP)/[DASH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming). Distribute the content using the buildin functionality of the media server or by the use of a CDN. Play the video on the client side with a player - [Flowplayer](https://flowplayer.org/)/[JwPlayer](http://www.jwplayer.com/)/[ViblastPlayer](http://www.viblast.com/player)/[VideoJs](http://www.videojs.com/)/your own Custome Player or a combination of the above. This is the hardest solution but it is also the best one in terams of scalability and platform reach. Such a solution can scale easily to thousands of people and reach all major browsers and mobile platforms.

I guess the third alternative is the one for you. You can read more about the whole capturing/publishing/transcoding/converting business in [BlookGeek's greate blog post](https://bloggeek.me/multipoint-webrtc-intro/).

Answer (score 0):

A webrtc based peer2peer connection is not the choice for one-to-n streaming. As there is no broadcast so far in webrtc you should consider another technique.